# jQuery is not sending correct GET data

Tags: jquery, html, get, radio-button, hidden

I'm trying to create an alternative to radio buttons by having the user click text instead of the radio button. I have that working but my problem is that the data being passed through the GET method is not correct. When I have the input type set to radio, the data is passed correctly(2nd image) but when I set the input type to hidden then the GET parameters are all being sent(1st image).

For example, in the image below the input type is set to hidden and if you look at the url it is sending unwanted parameters
[image]

THIS IS WHAT I WANT. The url contains only the parameters that I need but the input type is set to radio, I want them hidden
[image]

HTML:
class="span-background" just sets the color background

```
<div id="browse-settings">
Browse For: 
<span name="GN" value=0 class="span-background" >Female</span>
<span name="GN" value=1>Male</span>
<br>

Orientation: 
<span name="OR" value=0 class="span-background">Straight</span>
<span name="OR" value=1>Gay</span>
<span name="OR" value=2>Bi</span>
<span name="OR" value=3>All</span>
<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="GN" value=0 checked>
<input type="hidden" name="GN" value=1>

<input type="hidden" name="OR" value=0 checked>
<input type="hidden" name="OR" value=1>
<input type="hidden" name="OR" value=2>
<input type="hidden" name="OR" value=3>

<input  name="search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#browse-settings span").click(function() {
    $name = $(this).attr('name');
    $value = $(this).attr('value');

    $('span[name='+$name+']').removeClass('span-background');
    $(this).addClass('span-background');

    $('input[name='+$name+']').removeAttr('checked');
    $('input[name="'+$name+'"][value="'+$value+'"]').attr('checked',true);
});
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's valid HTML... all the values really should be in quotes.

Comment: with css3 you can use checkbox without javascript like this [http://jsfiddle.net/xEnF7/](http://jsfiddle.net/xEnF7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you realise that by adding click events to span elements you've made your page inaccessible to users who can't (or who choose not to) use a mouse or other pointing device. If you feel you must implement your own pseudo-radios, in my opinion it would be better to use anchor elements because then the user can tab to them and "click" them from the keyboard.

Anyway, the problem is that standard radio buttons only get submitted if they are checked, which means the request will only contain one parameter with the name from the radio button group. But hidden elements are *all* submitted.

The solution is to use a single hidden element per group of "radios" and set that one element's value as appropriate:

```
Browse For: 
<span name="GN" value=0 class="span-background" >Female</span>
<span name="GN" value=1>Male</span>
<br>

Orientation: 
<span name="OR" value=0 class="span-background">Straight</span>
<span name="OR" value=1>Gay</span>
<span name="OR" value=2>Bi</span>
<span name="OR" value=3>All</span>
<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="GN" value=0>    
<input type="hidden" name="OR" value=0>    
<input  name="search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

With corresponding JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#browse-settings span").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            name = $this.attr('name');        
        $('span[name='+name+']').removeClass('span-background');
        $this.addClass('span-background');        
        $('input[name='+name+']').val( $this.attr('value') );
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm89q/

Note that the informal convention on naming variables is that you use the `$` prefix for variables that will be jQuery objects, like my `$this`, above, but *don't* use the prefix for other variables, so not on `name`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this?